# JSTL iterating through an arrayList, seems to delete data

Tags: java, jsp, collections, jstl

Alright so I am working on a JSP that displays events from a chosen year. It works fine for 2012, but when 2013 is selected it doesn't work. It could be because there is no data there, but the months should still display.

Keep in mind I am an intern on my sophomore year of CS

Heres the method to populate an arraylist of months.

```
public List getMonths() {
    List months = new ArrayList();

    Map tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "January"); 
    tempMap.put("value", 1); 
    months.add(tempMap); 

    tempMap  = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "February"); 
    tempMap.put("value", 2); 
    months.add(tempMap); 

    tempMap   = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "March"); 
    tempMap.put("value", 3); 
    months.add(tempMap); 

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "April"); 
    tempMap.put("value", 4); 
    months.add(tempMap); 

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "May");
    tempMap.put("value", 5);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "June");
    tempMap.put("value", 6);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "July");
    tempMap.put("value", 7);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "August");
    tempMap.put("value", 8);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "September");
    tempMap.put("value", 9);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "October");
    tempMap.put("value", 10);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "November");
    tempMap.put("value", 11);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    tempMap.put("month", "December");
    tempMap.put("value", 12);
    months.add(tempMap);

    tempMap = new HashMap();
    return months;
}
```

Then I use this code to set the attributes:

```
request.setAttribute("months", getMonths());    
request.setAttribute("parkEvents", parkEventsList);
request.setAttribute("parkYears", parkYearsList);
request.setAttribute("currentYear", year);
```

and here is the JSTL code that should display the months, but it seems as if the loop "c:forEach var="months" items="${months}" does not iterate when the year is 2013. Any ideas?

```
<div>
    <form>
        <select onchange="javascript:window.open(this.value,'_self')">
        <c:forEach var="years" items="${parkYears}">
        <option value=/events.html?display_year=${years}<c:if test="${currentYear == years}"> selected="selected"</c:if>>${years}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>

    </form>
    </div>

<c:set var="years" value="${currentYear}"/>
<div class="generaltext">
  <!-- begin accordion -->
<div class="accordion" id="${years}" style="margin-top: 20px; display: none;"><!-- begin fas section -->

    <c:forEach var="months" items="${months}">
        <div class="section">
        ${years}
            <div class="sectionHeader inactiveHeader" id="${months.value}${years}SectionHeader">
            <a onclick="_showSectionContentContainer('${months.value}${years}Section'); return false;" href="#">
            <img id="${months.value}${years}SectionArrow_down" alt=""  src="/export/resources/images/arrows/grayRightSmall.gif" />
            <img id="${months.value}${years}SectionArrow_right" alt="" style="display: none;" src="/export/resources/images/arrows/grayDownSmall.gif" />${months.month} ${years}</a>
            </div>

            <div class="sectionContent" id="${months.value}${years}Section" style="display: none;"><br/>
        <c:set var="counter" value="0" />
            <c:forEach var="event" items="${parkEvents}">
                <c:if test="${event.eventYear == years && event.eventMonth == months.value && event.eventDay != counter}">
                    </br><b> ${event.eventMonth}/${event.eventDay}/${event.eventYear}</b></br>
                <c:set var="counter" value="${event.intEventDay}" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${event.eventYear == years && event.eventMonth == months.value && event.eventDay == counter}">
                    - <a target="_blank" href="http://fwp.mt.gov/eCalendar/ViewItem.html?cal_item_id=${event.id}&dtwhen=${event.intStartingDate}">${event.description} </a><br/>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach> 
            </div>

        </div>  
        </c:forEach>


</div>        <!-- end accordion -->
</div>
```

Comment: aren't you continuously overriding data in `Map`

Comment: No, he's creating a new instance each time.

Comment: Please consider using generics. So `List<Map<String, String>>` and `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: I have no experience with generics, but I will look into it. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: oh I see, I guess I am using some generics. Earlier in the JSP I declare the arrayList like so:

    List<String> parkYearsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Event> parkEventsList = new ArrayList<Event>();

Comment: Use objects rather than Maps. You should have a Month class, with a name and a value properties. This Month class could also be an enum.

Comment: I reformatted your code; take a look at it now and the problem might jump out at you.